# Upgarding directly to to Ag-Grid 31 in StencilJS using codemod

Tags: ag-grid, stenciljs

I have used third-party dependency Ag-Grid in StencilJs. I have an older version. I want to upgrade to v31 directly using the codemod mentioned in the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/upgrading-to-ag-grid-31/

However, when I run the command `npx @ag-grid-community/cli@31.0 migrate`, I am getting the following error:

```
npx: installed 2 in 27.155s
Cannot find module 'node:util'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\20860\node_modules\@ag-grid-community\cli\index.cjs
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating node got the codemod to work for me make sure you are above version 15.

Comment: Thanks, it showed that the migration was complete. But it is unable to modify any files. Getting final message as `Migration completed in 42675ms (0 modified, 209 unmodified, 0 failed, 209 total)`.

Did it work for you? I mean did it modify the components?

Comment: Yeah but the changes were pretty small like adding/removing parentheses. The codemod wasn't that useful for me to be honest it was more effective to go to fix errors as they appeared and use the changelog to fix them manually.